# Was Einstein original formula E =1/2 m c^2?

Tags: theoretical-physics, relativity-theory

I read somewhere that, but unfortunately I cannot retrace where, can you help me find a reliable source?

Actually, they said a sad story, hardly believable: They stated that Einstein had circulated a different version of the formula, with a 1/2 factor, but someone accused him of plagiarism, because that formula had already been put forward by someone else. 
Later, in the printed version, he changed the formula to the current form.

Can you tell me if that is true and who had suggested the 1/2 formula and who accused him of plagiarism?

Comment: Using the same formula would not be plagiarism, and changing a factor would just make it wrong. Interestingly the Lorentz ether theory had the EM mass corresponding to $E = \frac{3}{4}mc^2$. As far as I know no theory used a factor of one half.

Comment: Whoever told you this story seems not to understand very much about how science works or about the logical structure of relativity.